# deny any writing to given app and its children

Tags: ubuntu, selinux

So I have a Python app (which spawns other processes) which I want to deny any writing. It seems like a job for SELinux. Could you describe the steps needed to accomplish this, or perhaps direct me to some good reading resource, since from what I've found there aren't too many.

Comment: have you looked at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/?  pysandbox may give you the flexibility you want to deny filesystem writes.

Comment: Does it still need read permissions for stuff?  @Tim Kennedy's answer is a good place.  The more app-type agnostic way to do this is using chroot, and just putting it in a directory it has no write permissions to (how named works).

Comment: well, after all I ended up doing this with apparmor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under every OS, it's quite hard to do this, at the moment. Chrome developers have made some progess in this area, but it's still hard. They came with a solution about 22k lines of code (LOC) for Win* systems and 11k LOC for Linux.

In recent news, FreeBSD 9.0 was announced with [Capsicum](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/capsicum/), a framework designed for this purpose, but it can work only on *BSD systems.

On Linux, you can avoid SELinux or AppArmor using seccomp. See this [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/332974/) for more details and sample usage. But it's really hard: it's an all or nothing feature for system calls like read or write.

There is currently a new approach on-going in the LKML, using Berkeley Packet Filter, see [this post](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/11/260) of Will Drewry.

Comment: Lots of interesting stuff. I found rather easy way out: [setrlimit](http://rextester.com/KAKN22727) system call. Parent sets `setrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, 0)` and all its children are unable to write non-zero sized files. They are unable to do something like `setrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, non-zero)` as well, so this seems rather secure. I've used it to be able to run user-submitted code, here is an example: [rextester](http://rextester.com/RGXZM11946)